# Save login info to apple keychain in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to save user's login username and password to apple's keychain is it possible? If so how?

Here is how when you login to instagram you can fill in user login data through keychain:[image: Example in instagram]

Comment: Did you try to use https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage ?

Comment: Thanks I'll try it. Couldn't find it before

Comment: Did you find the correct solution for it?