# How to allow user to save/fill login info on/from Keychain/Keystore in Flutter

Tags: flutter, keystore, keychain, flutter-secure-storage

### What I want to achieve

- Save login credentials (email and password) on Keychain/Keystore.
- Fill login form when a user selects corresponding login info from Keychain/Keystore just like attached with some hints shown above keyboard. [Example behavior from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582718/save-login-info-to-apple-keychain-in-flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6rDX.png)
- Being able to delete the credentials from Keychain/Keystore directly when a user wants to.

### What I have tried

I have been successful saving and fetching email and password using flutter_secure_storage, but I cannot locate where they are on Keychain. I want to set domain or app bundle id or something to let Keychain/Keystore know that the credentials are for this app, but I cannot find such settings on flutter_secure_storage.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just want to know how to implement such feature.